# Jquery file picker from server

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, file

I'm making a form in php. I want the visitor to either upload an image (that part is done) or select one from the uploaded files. Is there any cool jQuery/php script that will solve this?

I'm thinking a small dialog that shows all the images from a selected folder. When the visitor clicks on foo.jpg (with thumbnail) the value in the text field would be "foo.jpg"

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I also added how to make a thumbnail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just scan the images directory like that:

```
                  <?php  $dir    = '/path/to/dir';
        $files1 = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($files1 as $value) {
        echo '<p class="images">'.$value.'</p>';
echo '<img class="clickableimg" id="'.$value.'" src="path/to/'.$value.'" />';
        } ?>
```

And you can add event on class 'images':

```
<script>
$(".images").click(function() {
var choosenpic = $(this).html();
$("#yourinputfieldID").val(choosenpic);
});
   $(".clickableimg").click(function() {
var choosenpic = $(this).attr('id');
$("#yourinputfieldID").val(choosenpic);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Cool! Do you know how to make the image clickable as well?